# Incorporate servlet in worklight project

Tags: servlets, ibm-mobilefirst

I have created one Worklight Project, which contains application that downloads the documents using one `servlet`. Is it possible to put this `servlet` within the same worklight project?
If yes, then how to put it?

Currently I have separate "Dynamic Web Project" for this single `servlet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To declare your servlet, you'll need to edit web.xml, which resides inside the .war file that is generated by Worklight Studio, which you then need to deploy to your application server.

However, whenever you run the project (Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server) the .war file  gets re-generated, so you will find yourself losing your added servlet every time.

So while it is possible technically, it is not a very viable way to integrate your servlet.
I would say that your current approach is better.

Comment: Can you please tell me, how to add Servlet in my project? I know the risk of losing it, but still I want to know.

Comment: You would need to declare it in the web.xml file, which is inside the .war file that can be found in the bin folder of your project.

Comment: And according to my knowledge, I don't have any control on the generation of the web.xml file that is reside in war file of the project, correct?

Comment: Correct. You can alter it after it is generated and deploy it, but if you ever re-build your project in Worklight Studio Again, your changes will be lost and you'll need to re-apply them.